# Correct iOS 10 click to call actions

Tags: ios, objective-c

So ive been messing around with xcode for a few days now and learning from other tutorials for my own personal pleasure, however i cant seem to figure out these warnings.

I have built a small application that goes from a parse server (just as a test). When i come to use the click to call (or whatever) features it causes the application to crash

so it drags data from withing the table like Email, Phonenumber, web address etc.

i cant make heads of tales as to what to change for this to work in iOS 10, its a simple click to call button from when the number is dragged and displayed from the parse.

```
@IBAction func phoneCallButt(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let aURL = URL(string: "telprompt://\(storeObj[STORES_PHONE]!)")!
     if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL:options:(aURL) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(aURL)
   }
}
```

Xcode suggests using OpenURL:options:competitionHandler but this neither works or creates anything worthwhile as i still get the warnings

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a noneditable selectable UITextView to display the phone number. It has "tap a phone number to dial the number" functionality built right in, in a standard way.

Comment: would that be to replace the UIapplication?

Comment: It would replace all your code. With a text view, you display the phone number and the user can tap it to call the number, with no code at all from you.

Comment: thanks ill gove this a go shortly, ill let you know the results